# Clearing Windows' Clipboard While Using Sikuli Or Jython

Tags: clipboard, jython, sikuli

I'm trying to clear the Windows' clipboard using Sikuli or Jython.

I'm currently using the clipboard to grab user entered text from a textbox. I use the clipboard to check if the user entered text before clicking a button. I want to check if the textbox was left empty before the button was clicked.

The problem that I am having is that once the clipboard is used, I am unable to clear it. So the value in the clipboard is returned to my script every time the button is clicked.

I need to be able to clear the clipboard after grabbing the user entered text from it, or find a way to read the textbox without using the clipboard.

Help.

Thanks in advance,

Marwan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Jython, you can do as follows to set the contents of the clipboard to an empty string, which would be something like clearing it.

```
from java.awt.datatransfer import StringSelection
from java.awt.datatransfer import Clipboard
from java.awt import Toolkit

toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard()
clipboard.setContents(StringSelection(""), None)
```

And as follows to read the contents of the clipboard as a string:

```
from java.awt.datatransfer import DataFlavor
contents = clipboard.getContents(None)
print contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks! I ended up using the following to retrieve the text from the textbox into the clipboard then into my variable.  `type(image_1,"a", KeyModifier.CTRL) # Select all text`  `type("c", KeyModifier.CTRL) # Copy to clipboard`  `message_text = Env.getClipboard()`

Comment: I forgot to note that in my comment above, the code used is for Sikuli.